# Multiple matching in react-router or ambiguous routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a task to build routing which maintains 2 type of components: sidebar and content. If the url contains `category-:type` I have to render Sidebar component and if url contains any content type like `profile`, `about` or `seller` I have to render proper content.
If create `<Route />` for each combination of sidebar and content type there will be a lot of items.
How can I build routing for this purpose? 
As I know I can't use routing like `<Route path="/**/:profile" component={Profile}>` because if Router will match this path it will stop and avoid other comparison.

Here is my current routing

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, routing);
ReactDOM.render(
   <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Base}>
         <IndexRedirect to="signin" />
         <Route path="n=:id/:title" component={Item} />
         <Route path="search(/:type)" component={require_auth(Search)} />
         <Route path="people(/:type)" component={require_auth(People_Layout)} />
         <Route path="person/:id" component={require_auth(Person_Scene_Layout)} />
         <Route path="signin" component={Signin} />
         <Route path="signup" component={Signup} />
         <Route path="profile" component={require_auth(Profile)} />
      </Route>
   </Router>
   , document.querySelector('#appRoot')
);
```

So, I have to extend this code to allow navigation on sidebar at the same time. I need to preserve current routing and add routing for matching Sidebar, something like `<Route path="category-:type/n=:id/:title" component={Item} />`. This routing can render both `<Sidebar/>` and `<Item/>` components but to make this work with all other routing I have to double almost all existing routes.

Comment: Can't understand the exact question. Perhaps a little more explaination could help

Comment: Make your question proper, by showing your exact `routes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, If I understand your question correctly, you have the requirement to Render 
components dynamically based on the Router Params like

1. Navigation Component - Some Sidebar Navigation
2. Content Components - profile, about , seller etc.

So, you can not directly filter the Components and Inject in Router. 
But what you can do is basically

1. Initiate a Parent-Components on any Router navigation by using **path="/*"**
2. and Inside the Parent-Component that, check for the Value of Router Pamas / Queries by

> this.props.location.query.yourParamName

and based on that, inject you Child-Component i.e. Navigation or Content.

```
<Router history={hashHistory} >
     <Route path="/*" component='ParentComponent'/>      
</Router>


export default class CartItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // check for Router Params and decide the Child Componenton on fly using any conditional statement.
        // var Component = this.props.location.query.yourParamName
        return (
            <div className='parent-wrapper'>
               React.createElement(Component, props, ...children)
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. My first intention was same. But this approach has few drawbacks: if route will be more complex with internal children it can breake this solution. I'll try to use this solution if i'll fail to find any other

Comment: Just put the route at the end in the router as path="/*" will match with any URL.  I didn't find any drawbacks, so it would be great if can can provide some scenario.   Also, you can mark my Answer as Accepted or Upvote it if fulfilled your requirement.